# iphone image move like another image

Tags: iphone, image, animation

I have an image which is rotating and what I want is that a second image to be stuck on it and it rotate just as the first. Please, how can I do this?

Comment: Is is possible for you to add the image onto the background image before the rotation (i.e. make a single image out of the two by overlaying the pixels).  If that is possible you wouldn't need to worry about rotating the two independently.

Comment: Is rotating image animated image by its nature(a gif kind of)?

Comment: what I want is to rotate by code and not gif. And that another image stick on it thus it rotate with him

Comment: Is it acceptable to make the second view a subview of the first? Then the same transform will be applied without any extra effort on your part, and it's up to you whether the parent clips the child so it doesn't matter if it doesn't actually fit inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my computer so I can't test this, but I think it should get you what you want.

```
// assuming you already have your views
// viewOne, viewTwo

[viewOne addSubview:viewTwo]; // add viewTwo to viewOne

// let's assume that you call this code here one time per second
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

// when this is 1.0, the image will rotate 360
// ... when it is .5, it should rotate 180, etc...
float rotationFactor = 0.1f;

// viewTwo's rotationFactor will be added to view 1's in the transform below
float rotationFactor2 = 0.1f;

viewOne.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * rotationFactor);
viewTwo.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * (rotationFactor + rotationFactor2);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```